# Loading dictionary value of specific type

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

How to load dictionary with specific type members while reading from different datatable calls?

1. I am populating Dictionary using method HashSet.ToDictionary
2. Then I making call to DB and want to load object (property Value1)
3. Finally I will make call to another DB and find and pre-populate the existing object's Value2 property

```js
HashSet < string > hashset = new HashSet < string > ();
Dictionary < string, CustomeObject > dictionary = new Dictionary < string, CustomeObject > ();
dictionary = hashset.ToDictionary(h => h, h => (CustomeObject) null);
while (firstreader.Read()) {
  if (dictionary.ContainsKey(firstreader.GetValue(1).ToString())) {
    dictionary[firstreader.GetValue(1).ToString()] = new CustomeObject() {
      Key = firstreader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
        Value1 = firstreader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
        Value2 = null
    };
  }
}


while (secondreader.Read()) {
  if (dictionary.ContainsKey(secondreader.GetValue(1).ToString())) {
    dictionary[secondreader.GetValue(1).ToString()] = new CustomeObject() {
      Key = "", //Persist the value from previous load
        Value1 = secondreader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
        Value2 = null;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write to the dictionary while iterating through both readers, you are instantiating a new object in both and assigning it to the dictionary value. So you create the object while reading `firstreader` and then you overwrite the object while reading `secondreader`.

What you need to do when reading `secondreader` is to check if the dictionary value is null. If not then just write Value2.

```
while (secondreader.Read()) {
  var myReadValue = secondreader.GetValue(1).ToString();
  if (dictionary.ContainsKey(myReadValue)) {
    if(dictionary[myReadValue] != null) {
      dictionary[myReadValue].Value2 = secondreader.GetValue(2).ToString();
    }
  }
}
```